# Programmatically popping navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, stack, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` defined below :

```
class MainPageViewController: UIPageViewController {


var view1 : UIViewController = UIViewController()
var view2 : UIViewController = UIViewController()
var view3 : UIViewController = UIViewController()

var current_index = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = self
    delegate = self

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let feed = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view1")

    view1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: feed)

    let requests = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2_1")

    let view2_1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: requests)
    let chat = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2_2")
    let view2_2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chat)
    let matches = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2_3")
    let view2_3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: matches)

    let view2 = UITabBarController()
    view2.viewControllers = [view2_1 , view2_2 , view2_3]

    let item1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Requests",image: UIImage(named : "request_filled_maintab") , tag: 0)
    let item2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Chats", image: UIImage(named : "chat_filled_maintab"), tag: 1)
    let item3 = UITabBarItem(title: "Matches", image: UIImage(named : "matches_filled_tab"), tag: 2)

    view2_1.tabBarItem = item1
    view2_2.tabBarItem = item2
    view2_3.tabBarItem = item3



    let story = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view3")
    view3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: story)

    view1.view.tag = 0
    view3.view.tag = 1
    view2.view.tag = 2

}
```

Basically there is 3 views in it, `view1` `view2` and `view3`. Now I'm adding push notification handling, what I need to do is if the user is in `view1` or `view3` (both navigation controllers) I need to pop the navigation stack to the root view controller and then proceed to `view2`.

So basically my layout is like this `UIPageViewController` ->

`UINavigationController` (view1)

`UINavigationController` (view3)

`UITabBarController` (view2)

I am trying this approach :

```
if var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
 while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
  }
    topController.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
  self.goToNextPage()
  self.goToNextPage()
  self.view2!.selectedIndex = 1
```

This code works if I am at the `rootViewController` of the `navigationController`, however in any other case it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not sure why.

(`goToNextPage` is a method which programmatically moves the pageViewController to the next page)